# disable key input when alert window is active

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I'm having an issue where users are just hitting enter multiple times when an alert box gets displayed so the 'ok' of the alert box is pressed with the enter key and they miss the message. Is there a quick way to disable key presses on alert windows and just allow for mouse input?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the alert box with your own modal implementation, because it prevents users from accessing your code until it's closed. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)

> Dialog boxes are modal windows - they prevent the user from accessing
>   the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed.
>   For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a
>   dialog box (or modal window).

Answer (score 0):

No, because it is a Web Browser API, it's behaviour is implemented on the Browser.

You can display the message as a modal, and disable it's button.

Try [this](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal) Jquery Plugin